# How can I get a specific number from all of my integer arrays in SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

hello everyone im new to postgress and I would like to know how to retreive all number 1 occurrences in my integer arrays.

my postgress version: "PostgreSQL 12.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit"

[image: Here is what im trying to do]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want `any()`?

```
select invitee
from invitationtable
where 1 = any(invitee)
```

This brings all rows where array `invitee` contains `1`.

Comment: yes and how could i pick out only the number ones from the result

Comment: I don't get your comment. This gives rows where the array contains `1`. Which result are you actually looking for?

Comment: uhmm my bad I was a little confused this is indeed what I was looking for. I will mark your answer as best answer thanks for the help!